# How do I display the top & bottom 5 row values along with custom row values in Matplotlib?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a dataframe that's about 750 odd rows, which is obviously excessive for a traditional bar chart. What I would like to do is have it display the Top 5 entries, the specific criteria that I'm looking for, and the bottom 5 entries.

The dataframe is something like this:

```
Animal  Score
0   Dog 1
1   Pig 2
2   Chicken 3
3   Cat 4
4   Fox 5
```

What I want to be able to do is display the bar graph so it selects the Top 5 (where 1 is highest) entries (Dog, Pig, Chicken, Cat, Fox) and then a specific entry in the list (the beetle) and then the bottom 5 entries (Tiger, Lion, Zebra, Gorilla, Seahorse) and the corresponding 'score' for those entries.

Is this even possible?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Update: The original answer gave me additional entries on the right-side of the graph, no matter how many times I modified the concat field. Perhaps due to the 750 entries in my df? Answer: NaN values were giving me blank values, which is the reason. These have been taken into account by me.

Comment: Yes this is possible, do you want both the top and bottom 5 on the same chart?

Comment: @Luke all should be on the same chart, yes thank you Luke!

Comment: Just to confirm, you want the top and bottom 5 as well as custom entries ?

Comment: yeah mate that's right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Importing Dependencies
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Creating DataFrame
data = {'Animal': ['Dog', 'Pig', 'Chicken','Cat','Fox','Hawk','Dolphin','Squirrel','Lizard','Shark','Ant','Beetle','Termite',
'Kangaroo','Opossum','Whale','Jellyfish','Seahorse','Gorilla','Zebra','Lion','Tiger'], 'Score': [_ for _ in range(23) if _ != 0]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

#Add custom entries here
custom_df = df.loc[df['Animal'].isin(['Beetle', 'Ant'])]

# Create new df
new_df = pd.concat([df[:5], df[-5:], custom_df])
new_df.sort_values(by=['Score'], inplace= True)
new_df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace= True)

# Creating the bar plot
plt.bar(new_df['Animal'], new_df['Score'])
plt.xticks(rotation=90) 
plt.xlabel("Animals")
plt.ylabel("Score")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I'm going to plead newbie status with matplotlib but for the `data = {'Animal': ['Dog', 'Pig',`... section, do I need to list out all 750 rows? or can I just go `data = dfdata` for example?

Comment: The code definitely works in the situation presented, however when applying it to my dataset it's giving me blank values.

Comment: --unable to edit above due to time limit-- The code definitely works in the situation presented, however when applying it to my dataset it's giving me blank entries on the X-axis, regardless of what I modify the `([df[:5], df[-5:], custom_df])` to be. What could be the reason? Furthermore, the solution doesn't name the entries, instead just assigning a number, which doesn't show what the entries represent?

Comment: I'm unable to understand what _blank entries_  refers to, please update your question. I have used `new_df.plot(kind='bar')`  for a simple visualization, you can use `matplotlib` or seaborn to plot the same dataframe instead to ensure you have animal names on the axis

Comment: The question header mentioned it was for matplotlib, so I think there's been a miscommunication.

Comment: Cheers mate. Just as an answer to your blank entries question,  blank entries refers to the number 7, 8, 9 (for example) having no bar, it's just blank. Even if I modified the numbers in the concat, there was always at least 1 number that had blank values.

Comment: I would be great if you updated your question with the issue

Comment: I have been trying for the last hour or so to add data labels outside the top of the bars and for the life of me, I cannot get it. Understood if you need a new question raised to be answered, but if not can the above me modified to include data labels?

Comment: It's best you post your new issues in a new question and I'll answer them there